# Multiple row selction not working in advanceddatagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml, multipleselection

In the adobe flex documentation it says that to make multiple rows selectable that I should add `allowMultipleSection = "true"` and `selectionMode = "multipleRows"`. For some reason in my Advanced Data grid it's not working. I only needed add `selectionMode`because `allowMultipleSection` was already there. So, what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick demo app and all I needed was the selectionMode="multipleRows".  How are you trying to do the selection? You can select a range by clicking on a row, then holding the shift key and clicking on another row to select all the rows between them, inclusive. Or use the (control on windows, command on mac) key to add individual rows to the selection. I have seen issues before where certain key presses  were getting swallowed either by the system or something in the app if you are using some advanced custom gui components in the container or in the cell's item renderer.

This demo app works for me to do multiple selection. Does it work for you? If not, something in the system may be intercepting certain key/mouse combos.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private const  dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{value:"Testing"},{value:"Testing"},{value:"Testing"}]);
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid allowMultipleSelection="true" selectionMode="multipleRows" dataProvider="{dp}">

        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Column" dataField="value" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. The problem is that is exactly what I did in the advanced data grid. `allowMultipleSelection` was already set equal to `true`. So, I just set selectionMode equal to `true`. There were a bunch of properties already there though. Is it possible that those are interfering with   it? How would check to see if the system is intercepting those key/combos?

Comment: The only thing I didn't include is the `dataProvider = "{dp}"`. They had that in the example in the adobe actionscript docs, but didn't say it was neccessary. What exactly does that do? Could that be causing my problem? Also didn't see your post until I was at home and I don't flex here with me. Will let you know if that works when I get in on monday.

Comment: Couldn't post the two of them together. Sorry

Comment: @user2127364, the `dataProvider = "{d}"` is just setting the dataProvider of the data grid using mxml binding, if you are setting it another way it doesn't matter. This simple app should tell you if it's a system thing or a problem with your code. If it's something in your app, the easiest way to debug is probably to take out all of the options and add them in one by one until you find the one causing the problem.